# How do I load a dataframe into an Excel template on Amazon Web Service's S3?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, openpyxl

**Issue**

I have a dataframe. The template I want to use only has column headings. The column headings in the dataframe are identical to the template column headings. How do I paste the contents of the dataframe into the template excel sheet?

**Reprex**

***Example dataframe***

```
import pandas as pd

data_input = {'Area':['North', 'North', 'North',  'South', 'South', 'South',  'West', 'West', 'West',   'East', "East","East"], 
              "Sub-Area": ["North2", "North1", "North2",   "South2", "South1", "South2","West3", "West9", "West9", "East1", "East4", "East1"], 
              "Workers": [1,20,30, 2,33,5, 3,6,44, 1, 11, 111], 
              "Job1":["T", "T", "T",  "X","T", "T",  "T", "X", "T", "X","T", "T"],
              "Job2":["F", "X", "T",  "X","T", "F",  "T", "X", "F", "X","T", "T"],
              "Job3":["T", "F", "T",  "X","X", "F",  "F", "T","X",  "X","T", "T"]}
 
# Create DataFrame
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data_input)
```

***Attempt #1***

```
# Save dataframe to the template file on S3
with io.BytesIO() as output:
    with pd.ExcelWriter(output, engine='openpyxl') as writer:
        df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1',startcol = 0, startrow=2)
    data = output.getvalue()
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.Bucket('main_folder').put_object(Key='sub_folder/template.xlsx', Body=data)
```

Problem: The above solution just writes my dataset over the template file.

***Attempt #2: Appending the dataframe via mode = "a"***

```
# Save dataframe to the template file on S3
# Save file to S3

with io.BytesIO() as output:
# here I add mode = "a"
    with pd.ExcelWriter(output, engine='openpyxl', mode = "a") as writer: 
        df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1',startcol = 0, startrow=2)
    data = output.getvalue()
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.Bucket('main_folder').put_object(Key='sub_folder/template.xlsx', Body=data)
```

Problem: Error Message

```
BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

**Attempt 3**

In response to a comment from jsn, I tried to first append the df to the template and then load that to S3 but it overwrote all the formatting of the template again.

```
#downloading template
template = pd.read_excel('s3://main_folder/sub_folder/template.xlsx', sheet_name="Sheet1")

#appending the dataframe
template = template.append(df1)

#now loading to S3
with io.BytesIO() as output:
    with pd.ExcelWriter(output, engine='openpyxl') as writer:
        template.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
    data = output.getvalue()
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.Bucket('main_folder').put_object(Key='sub_folder/template.xlsx', Body=data)
```

***Any help would be appreciated***

Comment: Where are you parsing this original template file? From what I can see you're creating the new df, saving as excel and the uploading to S3. If there is a template file in S3, I would think you'd want to parse that first so you're left with a df with only column headings, then reading this new data and then concatenating them both to put back to S3?

Comment: Okay, I now did what you suggested (see Attempt 3). It just overwrites all the formatting in the original template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The `pandas` library may not be suited to store `xlsx` formatting state.
- The alternative here could be `openpyxl` library which lets you load a workbook and does integrate with pandas to append your data.

You could attempt to do something like this:

```
from io import BytesIO
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

import boto3
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows

# Load Template from S3
bucket_object = boto3.resource('s3').Bucket(bucket_name).Object(object_key)
content = bucket_object.get()['Body'].read()

# Input Data
data_input = {
    'Area': ['North', 'North', 'North', 'South', 'South', 'South', 'West', 'West', 'West', 'East', "East", "East"],
    "Sub-Area": ["North2", "North1", "North2", "South2", "South1", "South2", "West3", "West9", "West9", "East1",
                 "East4", "East1"],
    "Workers": [1, 20, 30, 2, 33, 5, 3, 6, 44, 1, 11, 111],
    "Job1": ["T", "T", "T", "X", "T", "T", "T", "X", "T", "X", "T", "T"],
    "Job2": ["F", "X", "T", "X", "T", "F", "T", "X", "F", "X", "T", "T"],
    "Job3": ["T", "F", "T", "X", "X", "F", "F", "T", "X", "X", "T", "T"]}

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data_input)

# Load Workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename=(BytesIO(content)))
ws = wb['Sheet1']

# Append contents of Input Data to Workbook
for r in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=False, header=False):
    ws.append(r)

# Save Workbook back to S3
with NamedTemporaryFile() as tmp:
    filename = '/tmp/{}'.format(object_key)
    wb.save(filename)
    s3_resource.Bucket(bucket_name).upload_file(Filename=filename, Key=dest_filename)
```

Reference material as follows:

- https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pandas.html
- https://danh-was-here.netlify.app/save-excel-workbook-to-aws-s3-with-python/

###### Note:

This was tested locally (i.e. without AWS) and the output suggested that formatting applied to the heading columns in the template file remained even after the new data was added.

Comment: Thank you jsn - I really appreciate your help with this. I tried the above with bucket name = "main_folder" and object_key = "sub_folder/template.xlsx". But a problem occurs in the last part from "with NamedTemporaryFile()..." I get the error message: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/sub_folder/template.xlsx' Any ideas?

Comment: No problem! So depends where this code is being run from. If you're running this locally then the `/tmp/` directory needs to pre-exist so you'll have to manually create it (it doesn't have to be `/tmp/` either could be anything -> E.g.`xyz/`). However, if you want to run this in Lambda for example, then the `/tmp/` is the path that lambda will use and does not require you to pre-create the path.

Comment: You're a star!! It all works now. I made one small change. I added s3 = boto3.client('s3') and changed "s3_resource" to "s3". It now works!! Thank you!!